# How do I filter inbox and only download emails that have attachments

Tags: python, exchangelib

I am filtering a fairly large inbox using exchangelib. I only want to look at emails that have attachments.

I tried to add the attachments=True clause in the filter but it does not work. Below is my code. Could someone tell me what is the correct way of doing this?

```py
account.inbox.filter(datetime_received__range=(start_time, end_time), sender=some_sender, attachments=True)
```

Comment: How is it not working? Please post the error message or the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to filter on the `has_attachments` filter instead. I don't think you can filter directly on an attachment. Also, you may want to only select the fields that you need, using `.only()`:

```
account.inbox.filter(
    datetime_received__range=(start_time, end_time),
    sender=some_sender,
    has_attachments=True,
).only('sender', 'subject', 'attachments')
```